# Derivation of the adjoint of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over any field $F$. A transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$, gives rise to the adjoint $V^* \leftarrow W^*:T^*$ of the dual spaces via:
$$ T^*(f)(\cdot) = f\circ T(\cdot) $$

Let $\beta:=\{v_i\}^n_1$ and $\gamma:=\{w_i\}^m_1$ be the basis for $V$ and $W$ respectively, and $\beta^*:=\{v^i\}^n_1$ and $\gamma^*:=\{w^i\}^m_1$ for their respective duals. That is:
$$ v^i(v_j) = \delta_{ij} ~\text{and}~ w^i(w_j) = \delta_{ij} \qquad \text{for all}~i,j$$

It can be shown that the matrix for $T$ with respect to the above basis, $[T]_\beta^\gamma$, is connected to the transpose of the matrix of $T^*$, $[T^*]^{\beta^*}_{\gamma^*}$:
$$ [T^*]^{\beta^*}_{\gamma^*} = \left([T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}\right)^t $$

To see this, we write out $T^*(w^i)$ for any index $i$, in terms of $\beta^*$. The coefficient of the $j^{th}$ term, i.e., $T^*(w^i)(v_j)$, i.e., the $(j,i)$ element of the matrix for $T^*$, is $w^i(Tv_j)$ which is just another way of writing the $(i,j)$ element of the matrix $T$.

> Assuming the field is the complex numbers, what do we naturally alter to get the usual equality between the matrix of $T$ and the hermitian matrix of $T$. In other words how does one square the inner product derivation into this view of things?

edit: Working backwards, one can make the dual vectors of $W^*$ conjugate-linear, i.e.: $f(\alpha x) := \bar{\alpha}f(x)$ for $f \in W^*$. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea.  Often in functional analysis, dual vectors are represented by
$$
\beta^* = \langle \beta,\cdot\rangle
$$
Where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the [sesquilinear inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition). Such an identification can generally be made on Hilbert spaces by the [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

The advantage of this seemingly strange choice of dual vector is that $\langle f,f \rangle$ is guaranteed to be real and non-negative.